# Is there an easy way to insert millions of records to a PostgreSQL's pre-existing table?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a table in my database with having a few columns and one of them is a foreign key to another table. When I try to insert a few records (less than a million) I use python's automation where the foreign key object is accessed early before the processing. For a CSV file containing the data, I use something like this:
CSV file contains some data like this:

```
    contract_no, date, symbol, buyer_broker, seller_broker, quantity, rate, amt
    2021020803000132,2021-02-08,ACL,13.0,38.0,20.0,1850.0,37000.0
    2021020803000180,2021-02-08,BSL,36.0,35.0,100.0,1850.0,185000.0
    2021020803000181,2021-02-08,CLB,36.0,42.0,10.0,1850.0,18500.0
    2021020803000182,2021-02-08,CLB,36.0,29.0,54.0,1850.0,99900.0
    2021020803000183,2021-02-08,BSL,36.0,34.0,22.0,1850.0,40700.0
    2021020803000267,2021-02-08,ACL,54.0,1.0,20.0,1887.0,37740.0
    2021020803000268,2021-02-08,ACL,54.0,57.0,100.0,1887.0,188700.0
    2021020803000301,2021-02-08,LBL,28.0,38.0,10.0,1887.0,18870.0
    2021020803000305,2021-02-08,LBL,28.0,1.0,10.0,1887.0,18870.0
    2021020803000356,2021-02-08,CLB,28.0,59.0,10.0,1887.0,18870.0
    2021020803000531,2021-02-08,LSL,16.0,1.0,10.0,1900.0,19000.0
    2021020803000550,2021-02-08,BSL,54.0,58.0,10.0,1900.0,19000.0
    2021020803000552,2021-02-08,ACL,38.0,58.0,10.0,1900.0,19000.0
    ....
```

I've imported the CSV file as:

```py
    file = open('floor_sheet_data.csv')
    read_file = csv.reader(file)
    data = []
    for record in read_file:
         try:
                obj = FloorSheet.objects.get(contract_no=record[0])
         except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                org = Organization.objects.get(symbol=record[2])

                fl_data = FloorSheet(
                    org=org,
                    contract_no=record[0],
                    date=record[1],
                    buyer_broker=record[3],
                    seller_broker=record[4],
                    quantity=record[5],
                    rate=record[6],
                    amount=record[7]
                )
                data.append(fl_data)
    
    FloorSheet.Objects.bulk_create(data)
```

This works fine when there are a small no. of records to insert into the database. The main problem is here: I have a CSV file with more than 100 million rows of data as shown in the CSV above. By following this same process It'll take more than 5 days to update all of this data even if I used the batch_create method.

I found a [solution](https://www.tractionondemand.com/blog/using-copy-in-postgres-for-importing-large-csvs/) that can copy CSV files directly to the PostgreSQL database but doesn't clarify the case when there is a foreign key element in the data like mine does.

If you know how can I achieve my goals here, I'd be very thankful to you!

Comment: copy the data in a new table, then you can handle the foreign key restarint

Comment: If  I am following `contract_no` is the FK and you want to insert only those lines in the CSV that do not have a c`contract_no` in `FloorSheet`. Is that correct? If so you cannot do that as part of the `COPY` process. You would need to do as @nbk suggests.

Comment: @nbk If I create a new table then I'll not be able to access these data from my other models without a foreign key. How would I then link the foreign key objects?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Actually symbol is used for the foreign key. Organizations with that symbol are searched in the Organization table and then the Floorsheet object is created based on that organization as a foreignkey. Is there any easy way?

Comment: No, not as part of `COPY`. Once you have the data in a separate table you can join to that table in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement on the underlying `FloorSheet` table.

Comment: Can I do something like create a new table after copying the data from my CSV file and then updating the foreign key value for each symbol and then copy that table to my database table? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. You will need to provide a self contained example as update to your question, preferably something not involving the ORM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240048/discussion-between-anjaan-and-adrian-klaver).